# How to store global values from a function?

Tags: c, pointers

In my function I calculate two different values (Esum and Eold) which I want to us global (out of the function). 
I want to work with pointers to store the values but I'm not used to this technique.

This is what my function looks like but cant store values global....Does NOT store Esum and Eold global... Not good !

```
float Eold = 0.0f;
float Esum = 0.0f;

void ConPI(float Target, float Value, float Esum, float Eold){
  E = Target - Value;
  Esum = Esum + E;
  Eold = E;
}
```

Now I am looking for a solution to use pointers for Esum and Eold to store the values global. I'm not used to work with pointers and need help for my function:

```
void ConPI(float Target, float Value, float Esum, float Eold, float *p, float *q){
  E = Target - Value;
  Esum = Esum + E;
  p = &Esum;

  Eold = E;
  q = &Eold;

}
```

This does actually not work. After jumping out of the function Eold and Esum becom 0.000 .... 
Maybe someone can help me to understand why this happens.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Correct, Eold and Ealt are the same variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this, based on your first function definition:

```
void ConPI(float Target, float Value, float *Esum, float *Ealt){
    E = Target - Value;
    *Esum = *Esum + E;
    *Ealt = E;
}
```

This way you pass in pointers to Esum and Ealt.  And you use the dereference operator when using them in the function.  Then you can call `ConPI` like this:

```
float Target, Value, Esum, Ealt;
...
ConPi(Target, Value, &Esum, &Ealt);
```

Now, each time that you call ConPi, Esum and Ealt get updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to `return` the address of your global variables, you'll need a pointer to pointer:

```
void ConPI(float Target, float Value, float Esum, float Ealt, float **p, float **q)
{
      E = Target - Value;
      Esum = Esum + E;
      *p = &Esum;

      Eold = E;
      *q = &Eold;
}
```

You would call `ConPI` like this:

```
float *copy1, *copy2;

ConPI(..., ..., ..., ..., &copy1, &copy2);
```

You do have (potential) issues in your code however:

1. Having a global and local variable named `Esum` creates what is called variable shadowing.  In `ConPI`, `Esum` refers to the local copy (i.e. not the global `Esum`).
2. `return`ing the address of this variable to the caller results in undefined behavior.